# Scipy solve_ivp : change max_step during running possible?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am solving the equation of motion essentially of elastic bodies dropping on an elastic surface. Through trial and error I found, that I only get reasonable results if I select `max_step` around 0.0001 with `solve_ivp`. Even normally good methods like Radau do not seem to give results without this.
I believe, this is only necessary if any of my bodies is close to the surface, and these distances are known during integration.
My question: can I change the value of `max_step` during the integration?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`solve_ivp` cannot handle dynamically changing step size, but `solve_ivp` is a wrapper to execute solvers of type `ODESolver` .  Using a `ODESolver` such as `Radau`, the `max_step` attribute can be changed. See [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems) although there is little examples on how to use the lower level class-based solvers.  Hopefully the example below can help.

For example, this code limits the step size to be no larger than 0.1.

```py
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, Radau
import numpy as np
def fun(t, y):
    return [1]
        
sol = solve_ivp(fun, [0, 1], [0], method="Radau", max_step=0.1)
print(np.diff(sol.t))
```

yields `[1.00e-04 1.00e-03 1.00e-02 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 8.89e-02]`

The following code is equivalent:

```
rad = Radau(fun, t0=0, y0=[0], t_bound=1, max_step=0.1)
step_size = []
while rad.status == "running":
    rad.step()
    step_size.append(rad.step_size)
print(np.array(step_size))
```

yielding `[1.00e-04 1.00e-03 1.00e-02 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 8.89e-02]` which is the same.

But now, we can modify the `ODESolver` object during the computation to change the maximum step size in the middle of the computation.

```
rad = Radau(fun, t0=0, y0=[0], t_bound=1, max_step=0.1)
step_size = []
while rad.t < 0.5 and rad.status == "running":
    rad.step()
    step_size.append(rad.step_size)
rad.max_step = 0.05  # modify max_step
while rad.status == "running":
    rad.step()
    step_size.append(rad.step_size)
print(np.array(step_size))
```

yields `[1.00e-04 1.00e-03 1.00e-02 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 1.00e-01 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 5.00e-02 3.89e-02]`

Comment: Dear Mathew, Thanks a lot! You explanations are so totally clear! (You explained 'events' of solve_ivp to me a good while ago, also completely clear!) Take care! Peter

Comment: I have one more question in this regard: the condition when to change the max_step size is available only in the finction called fun above. It is stored in a list. If any of the entries of the list is smaller than a small positive number, max_step would be reduced. My question: How can I get the information in this list, so I could use it the the loop suggested how to change max_step? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: I think, this should work, if I declare this list to be global (?)

Comment: I don't recommend using anything from the ODE solver function evaluations, as it doesn't necessarily represent the state at the ODE solution.  I would evaluate the function at the successful step.

Comment: Thanks! would I get the succesful step like this: if rad.success == True...? I cannot find much in the scipy.integrate.Radau documentation. Thanks a lot once again!!